# Getting Invalid scope for first_name,last_name facebook

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am using this code but getting an error of invalid scope

I would like to access this first name, last name and email.

can anyone help me with whats wrong in this.

is that because of the permission change in facebook??

or something else?

do i need to add something else.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        final LoginButton loginButton= (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","name"));
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {


                String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

                GraphRequest request= GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        getData(object);
                    }
                });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields","id,email,first_name,last_name");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }
        });

    }


    private void getData(JSONObject object)
    {
        try{
            email.setText(object.getString("email"));
            first_name.setText(object.getString("first_name"));
            last_name.setText(object.getString("last_name"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no permission called `name`. Looks like you are confusing permissions with fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
```

set this permission  and use this

```
protected void getUserDetails(LoginResult loginResult) {
        GraphRequest data_request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject json_object,
                            GraphResponse response) {

   //here is your login is success now your requirement is start From here
   //do your work
    Log.e("String Response from Facebook:>",json_object.toString())


                    }

                });
        Bundle permission_param = new Bundle();
  //width and height is optional parameters
        permission_param.putString("fields", "id,name,email,picture.width(120).height(120)");
        data_request.setParameters(permission_param);
        data_request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], especially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](//stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](//stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).

Answer (score 0):

istead of this

```
first_name.setText(object.getString("first_name"));
            last_name.setText(object.getString("last_name"));
        }
```

you should get the name direct from facebeook as

```
 facebookUser.name = object.getString("name");
```

Try and check it out and to get  first name and last name you should split it.

Answer (score 0):

I had passed name in permission with email which is not required after removing it worked. Thanx for your answers